# SSL reverse proxy buildpack for cloudfoundry buildpack which lacks SSL support?

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I'm using an out of the box buildpack for cloudfoudry lacking SSL support.

Can you recommend a SSL reverse proxy buildpack for cloudfoundry?

Plain text intra-cloud/inter-container http traffic is ok for me.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Generally the build pack does not need to support SSL.

This is because connections coming to your application first go to a load balancer where SSL is terminated.  The LB then proxies the connection unencrypted to the gorouter and onto your application.  Because SSL is terminated at the LB, the build pack only needs to setup your application to receive connections via HTTP.

Ex: Request Flow

```
Browser -(HTTPS)-> LB -(HTTP)-> gorouter -(HTTP)-> your app
                    [    Inside your Cloud                  ]
```

This generally works fine because everything behind the LB is inside a protected, internal network.

Comment: Thanks .. I've asked because on IBM Bluemix one couldn't upload custom certificates but this is solved now.